# NuGet how to apply properties to files

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am creating NuGet Package. I have put two files in `content` folder, exe and config files that will be added when user installs this package.

In addition I would like to change VS project properties for these two files.

What do I need to do for that when building the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "apply properties change" do you mean file system properties such last modified time, hidden flag, etc.?

If so there are a set of PowerShell scripts that are run (if they exist in your package) you can use to do this. It won't happen when you build the package, but it will run when somebody installs the package - which should have the same effect form the users point of view. You probably want either **`Init.ps1`** or **`Install.ps1`**.

From [Automatically Running PowerShell Scripts During Package Installation and Removal](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal) in the NuGet docs:

> A package can include PowerShell scripts that automatically run when
>   the package is installed or removed. NuGet automatically runs scripts
>   based on their file names using the following conventions:
>
> - **`Init.ps1`** runs the first time a package is installed in a solution.
>
>   - If the same package is installed into additional
>       projects in the solution, the script is not run during those
>       installations.
>   - The script also runs every time the solution is
>       opened. For example, if you install a package, close Visual Studio,
>       and then start Visual Studio and open the solution, the `Init.ps1`
>       script runs again.
> - **`Install.ps1`** runs when a package is installed in a project.
>
>   - If the same package is installed in multiple projects in a solution,
>       the script runs each time the package is installed.
>   - The package must have files in the content or lib folder for `Install.ps1` to run.  Just having something in the tools folder will not kick this off.
>   - If your package also has an `init.ps1`, `install.ps1` runs after `init.ps1`.
> - **`Uninstall.ps1`** runs every time a package is uninstalled.
> - These files should be located in the tools directory of your package.
> - At the top of your file, add this line: `param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)`
>
>   - `$installPath` is the path to the
>       folder where the package is installed
>   - `$toolsPath` is the path to
>       the tools directory in the folder where the package is installed
>   - `$package` is a reference to the package object.
>   - `$project` is a
>       reference to the EnvDTE project object and represents the project the
>       package is installed into. Note: This will be null in `Init.ps1`. In
>       that case doesn't have a reference to a particular project because it
>       runs at the solution level. The properties of this object are defined
>       in the MSDN documentation.
> - When you are testing `$project` in the console while creating your scripts, you can set it to `$project = Get-Project`

Comment: I would like to change properties of that file "Copy To Output directory" to "Copy Always" How can i do that?

Comment: @ArunRana For copy always set the value of CopyToOutput to 1.  For example
  $handle = $project.ProjectItems.Item($file)

 #set 'Copy To Output Directory' to 'Copy Always'
 $copyToOutput = $handle.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
 $copyToOutput.Value = 1