# NuGet: How can I change property of files with Install.ps1 file?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating NuGet package and for that I have created Nuspec manifest file. In `content` folder I have two files, `test.exe` and `test.config`. Now I would like to change property "Copy To Output Directory" of these the files to "Copy Always" in project, when any user installs this package.

I found related question [NuGet how to apply properties to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411249/creating-nuget-package-how-to-apply-properties-to-files), that shows can do this using PowerShell `install.ps1` script, but I have no idea how to create that file.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your install.ps1 file should look something like this.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$file1 = $project.ProjectItems.Item("test.exe")
$file2 = $project.ProjectItems.Item("test.config")

# set 'Copy To Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer'
$copyToOutput1 = $file1.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
$copyToOutput1.Value = 2

$copyToOutput2 = $file2.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
$copyToOutput2.Value = 2
```

Comment: // is not a comment in powershell, use # :) otherwise very useful, thanks

Comment: @brent: looking for some docs on accepted values for Item("CopyToOutputDirectory") i know this is a DTE enum but cant seem to find it :-/ a link to your reference would be great help to me and anyone who finds this answer.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a bit more detail on how to solve this problem end to end:

You need to do two things to ensure the status are set correctly on install...

1. Write the install.ps1 script to mark the status of the files.
2. Ensure the install.ps1 script is in the Tools directory in the nuget package.

**Install.ps1 Script**

The following example script will recursively mark every file in the "Content" and "View" directory as "Copy to newer".  Note this example script is written to make it clear to read and understand.  It will mark every file in the Content and Views folders in the root directory of the Visual Studios project.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

function MarkDirectoryAsCopyToOutputRecursive($item)
{
    $item.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { MarkFileASCopyToOutputDirectory($_) }
}

function MarkFileASCopyToOutputDirectory($item)
{
    Try
    {
        Write-Host Try set $item.Name
        $item.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 2
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host RecurseOn $item.Name
        MarkDirectoryAsCopyToOutputRecursive($item)
    }
}

#Now mark everything in the a directory as "Copy to newer"
MarkDirectoryAsCopyToOutputRecursive($project.ProjectItems.Item("Content"))
MarkDirectoryAsCopyToOutputRecursive($project.ProjectItems.Item("Views"))
```

**Copy To Tools**

You must copy the install.ps1 file to the Tools directory for script to be executed by nuget.  You can add the following to the nuspec template to do this.

```
<files>
   <file src="install.ps1" target="Tools"/>
</files>
```

Note in this case I have the install.ps1 file in the root of my Visual Studios project and marked as "Copy if newer".

Comment: The above was giving  

`Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"
At Tools\install.ps1:3 char:27
+ $project.ProjectItems.Item <<<< ("Content").ProjectItems.Item("file.jar").Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 1
    + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
`

I fixed this by changing
 
`MarkDirectoryAsCopyToOutputRecursive($project.ProjectItems.Item("Content"))`

to

`MarkDirectoryAsCopyToOutputRecursive($project))`

Comment: @Paul your suggestion sets **EVERYTHING** in your project to CopyIfNewer, which is probably not what you want.  you can use `$project.ProjectItems.Item("<folderNameHere>")` to set the properties only for files in that folder of your project.  This isn't 100% clear from the answer.