# How to change CopyToOutputDirectory on project reference via powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I created a nuget package which contains 3rd party assemblies so that I don't have to put them in a lib folder in every repo where I want to reference them.  The nature of the 3rd party libraries is that I cannot have their references set to copy to the output directory (it causes an error done the line with their deploy scripts).

To get around this I figured I could create a install.ps1 script in my nuget package and change the CopyToOutputDirectory property to Never.  I have not been able to find any examples of this on the web.  The only samples I find are related to content files existing in the ProjectItems collection (e.g. [Nuget - Setting CopyToOutputDirectory on content in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460869/nuget-setting-copytooutputdirectory-on-content-in-subfolders)).

I tried to modify this based on some other google searches and came up with this method to get the reference

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project) 

$configItem = $project.Object.References | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'ReferencedDll' }
```

Now $configItem does indeed hold the reference and I have verified this by doing a Write-Host $configItem.Name but I can't figure out how to change CopyToOutputDirectory at this point or find any MS docs on the object model of the reference.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was mixing up CopyLocal and CopyToOutputDirectory.  The solution was to do this after setting $configItem as I did above:

```
$configItem.CopyLocal = $false
```